# Set Bash script variable equal to function with parameters

Tags: bash, function, parameter-passing

I have a script that kicks off a database query dependent on dates.  Right now, the script defaults to yesterday's date:

```
function startDate() {
  date --date="yesterday" "+%Y-%m-%d";
}

START= "`startDate`"
```

What I want to do is pass an argument to the script, so that cron (or whatnot) can have configurable dates.  I am unable to get the right syntax for neither the function nor the function call:

```
function startDate() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]
  then 
    date --date="yesterday" "+%Y-%m-%d";
  else
    "$1"
  fi
}

START= "`startDate \"$1\"`"

$ sh shTest.sh 2014-05-19
shTest.sh: line 6: 2014-05-19: command not found
shTest.sh: line 10: : command not found
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BASH you can do:

```
START="$(startDate "$1")"
```

Also your function needs `echo $1`:

```
function startDate() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]
  then 
    date --date="yesterday" "+%Y-%m-%d";
  else
    echo "$1"
  fi
}
```